# Logos en geom_point

Tags: r, rstudio

He instalado la librería ggimage para colocar un logo por los puntos que salen por defecto en ggplot cuando utilizas la función geom_point. También he creado una columna "imagen" en mi dataframe con el link del logo que corresponde a cada equipo. Me interesaría saber como poder sustituir las imágenes que salen por defecto del logo de R y poner los escudos de los equipos. Mi código utilizado:

```
ggplot(Francia, aes(Gls., Ass)) + geom_point() + geom_image(aes(Gls., Ass), size=.05)
```

Mi columna creada dentro del df:

```
Francia$imagen <- c("https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/angers-sco-logo-41-220x300.png", "https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/fc-bordeaux-logo-41-245x300.png", "https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/stade-brestois-29-logo-41-247x300.png", "https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/dijon-fco-logo-0.png","https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/big/826.png?lm=1595457059","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/lille-logo-41-300x285.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4c/FC_Lorient_logo.svg/1200px-FC_Lorient_logo.svg.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/lyon-logo-41-259x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/olympique-de-marseille-91-232x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/fc-metz-logo-41-251x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/monaco-fc-logo-41-176x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/montpellier-logo-41-300x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/nantes-fc-logo-41-228x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/ogc-nice-logo-41-243x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/nimes-olympique-logo-41-258x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/psg-logo-escudo-paris-saint-germain-51-300x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/stade-de-reims-logo-41-300x300.png","https://es.logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/rennes-fc-logo-41-246x300.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Logo_AS_Saint-%C3%89tienne.svg/1200px-Logo_AS_Saint-%C3%89tienne.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Racing_Club_de_Strasbourg_logo.svg/1200px-Racing_Club_de_Strasbourg_logo.svg.png")
```

Y el gráfico, que me aparece con el logo de R:

[image: Aquí el gráfico]

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario mapear el argumento `image=` de la función `geom_image()` a la columna que tiene los URL.

```
ggplot(Francia, aes(x = GLS., y = Ass)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_image(image = imagen) #Aquí mapeo las URL a la columna.
```

No es necesario mapear de nuevo las coordenadas xy en la llamada a `geom_image()`, las hereda de la definición que está más arriba en la primera llamada a la función.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]